# Laravel storage can't be accessed

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing a system to upload and show some images, however I am confused about the correct way to access them once uploaded.

```
public function storeImage(Request $request)
{

    $request->file('image')->store('public/images');

    $filename = md5_file($request->file('image')) . '.' .  $request->file('image')->extension();
    $img = new Image;
    $img->path = 'storage/images/'.$filename;
    $img->save();

    return back();
}
```

This works fine, and I have symlinked `storage` as suggested, however if I use the `$filename` variable from the database I get a 404. What is the correct path to generate to insert as an inline image src attribute here?

The image tag looks like this:
`<img src="storage/images/89cdd31f2e0eeacceff96c2a0abb252f.jpeg">`
The folder is definitely symlinked as I can follow it in finder.

Comment: The folder is symlinked, but is the image there?

Comment: The image is there

Comment: Try adding a / before storage? Otherwise, it will try to load the folder relative to the webpage, instead of from the web root.

Comment: What's the URL of the page your `<img>` tag is in?

Comment: http://my-website.dev/home (homestead) and preceding slash does nothing :(

Comment: Since you're using a subdirectory, try adding `/home/` to the beginning of the path.

Comment: Can you share the command you used to set up the symlink? Your code is doing `store('public/images')`. If you've symlinked `storage/images` to `public/images` your `<img>` tag should probably just start with "/images/...", not `/storage/images/`.

Comment: Good idea, but `/home/` doesn't do anything either

Comment: I used `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Could it be a chmod issue? Or possible because of the virtual machine?

Comment: OK, so per https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#the-public-disk you should have the following: A folder called `storage/app/public`, a file at `storage/app/public/images/89cdd31f2e0eeacceff96c2a0abb252f.jpeg`, be able to access the symlinked `public/storage/images/89cdd31f2e0eeacceff96c2a0abb252f.jpeg`. Can you confirm all these via the CLI?

Comment: `me at macbook in ~/Projects/my-website/storage/app/public/images on master [!]`, `-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   5971 Sep 28 16:50 89cdd31f2e0eeacceff96c2a0abb252f.jpeg` and `lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff    54 Sep 27 19:32 storage -> /Users/me/Projects/my-website/storage/app/public`  
    

Makes no sense right? Sorry I can't put line breaks in this

Comment: How did you create the images folder? Because if you did it manually you could forget to give a proper rights to your www-data group (make sure that directory is writable by server)

Comment: `$request->file('image')->store('public/images')` is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed this.

`php artisan storage:link` does not work with homestead. Instead delete the folder, manually recreate them on the machine using `homestead ssh` and `ln -s ~/projects/my-website/storage/app/public/ ~/projects/my-website/public/storage`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the latest version of laravel, 5.3?

If so, have you tried using the [URL method from the Storage facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#file-urls) to acquire the image src URL?

Example:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

`$url = Storage::url('file1.jpg'); //acquire URL`

Comment: Yup, this doesn't work either and gives `/storage/89cdd31f2e0eeacceff96c2a0abb252f.jpeg` as the path.

Answer (score 0):

files should be stored in the directory `storage/app/public` so make sure that your files are stored in this directory.

After saving the file make sure to get the url of the file by passing file name as the argument.. here how I implemented

html form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="jobImage">
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image">
   </div>
   <input type="button" value="Upload Image" onclick="uploadImage()" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

jquery uploadImage function

```
function uploadImage(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{url('/')}}/uploadImage",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{csrf_token()}}"
            },

            data:new FormData($("#jobImage")[0]),
            method:"POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function(data){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                // $('#jobImageToDisplay').attr('src', '/public/uploads/' + data.image);

                $('#jobImageToDisplay').attr('src', data.url);
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

route in web.php

```
Route::post('/uploadImage','ControllerClass@uploadImage');
```

In the Controller class

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);


        if ($validator->passes()) {

            $input = $request->all();
            $uploadedImage = $input['image'];
            // put image to storage/app/public/uploads/images
            $name = Storage::put('/public/uploads/images/', $uploadedImage);

            $visibility = Storage::getVisibility($name);
            // set visibility to true
            Storage::setVisibility($name, 'public');

            // get the url of the uploaded file
            $url = Storage::url($name);
            // return the url
            return response()->json(['url' => $url]);
        }


        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you provide the correct APP_URL in the .env file

*config/filesystems.php*

```php
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
    'throw' => false,
],
```

*.env*

```php
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```