# Laravel linked storage folder can't be assessd

Tags: php, laravel

This is my route:

```
Route::post('/articles/image/upload','ArticleController@imageUpload');
```

This is my controller:

```
    public function imageUpload(Request $request){

        $path=$request->file('wangEditorH5File')->store('/');

        return asset('storage/'.$path);

      }
```

I am using rich text editor to allow a user to upload their image so I have to return a url to the text editor.

I made a symbolic link using:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

that creates a symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.

I also changed the default drive of filesystem from local to public before linked

```
return [


'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),



'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],
```

];

After all is set, the text editor returns an error message that tells me I can not get the url of the image.

It means I can't access the `storage` folder under `public` .

I tried to put an image in the css folder and change the `asset()` function

```
public function imageUpload(Request $request){

    $path=$request->file('wangEditorH5File')->store('/');

    return asset('css/111.jpg');

}
```

It works for css and image shows up.

Comment: Make sure you set the right permissions for `storage/app/public` directory.

Comment: Could give me further information?like docs or how to.Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.ru/#q=laravel+storage+directory+permissions). You're welcome.

Comment: @AlexM the permission is 777                                                  

lrwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Jul 17 10:42 storage

Comment: What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: You should check also permissions for `storage/app/public` (not only `storage`)

Comment: GET http://homestead.app/storage/i6rzbiHAEadgE9isJPcDne2bunhwyKLgCmKtMAtt.jpeg 404 (Not Found)    <- this is only message i got from chrome console.Is there any log in laravel i can take a look?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   4096 Jul 17 10:42 public       that is the permissions for storage/app/publi

Comment: either path is not created or file permissions. For file permissions don't make 777, 755 is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

If you create symlink under windows,here is the solution

> `php artisan storage:link` does not work with homestead. Instead
>   delete the folder, manually recreate them on the machine using
>   `homestead ssh` and `ln -s ~/projects/my-website/storage/app/public/
>   ~/projects/my-website/public/storage.`

[From other question ->Laravel storage can't be accessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752361/laravel-storage-cant-be-accessed)

Comment: vagrant have some problems related with permissions directory
yes, thanks, you saved my hour